# My database is not updating ,using jdbc connection

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I have tried this to connect database. But it is not working. I don't understand where is the problem

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try{
        String value1 = jTextField5.getText();
        String value2 = jTextField6.getText();
        String value3 = jTextField7.getText();
        String value4 = jTextField10.getText();
        String value5 = jTextField11.getText();
        String value6 = jTextField12.getText();
        String value7 = jTextField1.getText();
        String sql = "update Account  set  Nationality=' "+value1+" ' , Gender=' "+value2+" ' ,Address=' "+value3+" ' , Caste=' "+value4+" ' , Mob=' "+value5+" ' ,Sec_Q=' "+value6+" '  where  Name =' "+value7+" ' "; 

       pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
       pst.execute( );
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Profile  updated");
          }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Name =' "+value7+" '` Too much spaces. Use Prepared Statements and your problems go away

Comment: Consider adding any error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use PreparedStatement in the right form:

```
 String value1 = jTextField5.getText();
 String value2 = jTextField6.getText();
 String value3 = jTextField7.getText();
 String value4 = jTextField10.getText();
 String value5 = jTextField11.getText();
 String value6 = jTextField12.getText();
 String value7 = jTextField1.getText();
 String sql = "update Account  set  Nationality=? , Gender=? ,Address=? , Caste=? , Mob=? ,Sec_Q=?  where  Name =?"; 

pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, value1);
pst.setString(2, value2);
pst.setString(3, value3);
pst.setString(4, value4);
pst.setString(5, value5);
pst.setString(6, value6);
pst.setString(7, value7);
pst.execute( );

conn.commit(); //-->>>Don't forget the commit
```

Comment: Omg!! thanks a lot.it worked.really appreciate it :)